# Wordpress: custom contact page page for each member

Tags: wordpress

Anyone know how to make a custom contact page for each member. Problem comes from creating the url, something like /profile/admin/contact . Maybe you guys know a plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress User](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-users/)s plugin is the closest I found to what you need.  It doesn't create a contact form but does create a profile page for each user.

I don't have time right now, but modifying the code of the plugin to create a contact form on each user's profile page would be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own template? You could customise the form with some of the built in WP functions like on here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user